# get the html tags after edit my info (asp.net)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

sorry for my bad language.
i'm new asp.net developing.

1- I have one table have more than rows and columns created dynamicly by selected the number of row and columns.

2- When i create table i create also this conrols for every row:-

*A- One textbox , one label ,one combo box and color picker.

B- Color picker shown when clicked on any cell to change background color for selected cell.

C- The label show what i write in the  textbox after click on button.

D-Select from combobox any thing.

E-The controls , rows and cells have uniqe id.*

**I already create this table with conrols and every thing ok.**

**The problem:**
*1- i'm trying to show in the label what i write in the text

2- I want to get the html tags for the table created included every thing inside it with selected data and the color changed and what i write in textbox to save after that in mydata base.*

**thanks,**

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand your first problem can be solved in the code-behind.

C#:

```
// Fire the text change for whatever event you need. ie a button click.
protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text;

}
```

Unfortunately I can't understand your second problem. Try explaining your situation and problem again.

If you need to send/retrieve data to/from a database there are a few steps you will need to take depending on the server you are running on. You can use databound controls or send data manually in the code behind.

Here's a video that may help you.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CKdQUgrL3Gg

and here's an article that may also help.

http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/archive/2010/12/19/retrieve-data-from-an-asp-net-application-using-ado-net-2-0-connected-model.aspx

Comment: ok what i want is if i have textbox and combobox and every one have data entered by user ,i want to save the html tags included the textbox tage with the value and also the combobox tag with selected text

Comment: the first one i want it using javascript